# d3 circle pack - access data (for text labels)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a modified circle pack implementation where I append the roots adjacent to each other (as opposed to being in one giant circle). What has eluded me until now is after I have created the circle packs, how can I retrieve the data if I wanted to add text to each circle. Here is what I'm working with:

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 1080;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

//var tsvData = d3.tsv('circle-pack-data.tsv');

//tsvData.then(function(rawData) {

/*
  var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
    return {id:d.id, parentId:d.parentId, size:+d.size}
  });
*/


  var data = [
    [
    {'id':'1Q19'},
    {'id':'pooled','parentId':'1Q19','size':29.5},
    {'id':'spv','parentId':'1Q19', 'size':11},
    {'id':'single','parentId':'1Q19', 'size':200}
  ],

  [
  {'id':'2Q19'},
  {'id':'pooled','parentId':'2Q19','size':31},
  {'id':'spv','parentId':'2Q19', 'size':15},
  {'id':'single','parentId':'2Q19', 'size':171}
],

[
{'id':'3Q19'},
{'id':'pooled','parentId':'3Q19','size':28},
{'id':'spv','parentId':'3Q19', 'size':12},
{'id':'single','parentId':'3Q19', 'size':152}
],

[
{'id':'4Q19'},
{'id':'pooled','parentId':'4Q19','size':25},
{'id':'spv','parentId':'4Q19', 'size':214},
{'id':'single','parentId':'4Q19', 'size':101}
],
];

var colorMap = {
  '1Q19':"#e7eef8",
  '2Q19':"#e7eef8",
  '3Q19':"#e7eef8",
  '4Q19':"#e7eef8",
  'pooled':"#f6d18b",
  'spv':"#366092",
  'single':"#95b3d7"
};

    for (var j=0; j <(data.length); j++) {

  var vData = d3.stratify()(data[j]);

  var vLayout = d3.pack().size([250, 250]);

  var vRoot = d3.hierarchy(vData).sum(function (d) { return d.data.size; });
  var vNodes = vRoot.descendants();
  vLayout(vRoot);

  var thisClass = "circ"+String(j);

  var vSlices = graphGroup.selectAll('.'+thisClass).data(vNodes).attr('class',thisClass).enter().append('g');

  //console.log(vNodes)

  vSlices.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
          return d.x+(j*300)
      })
      .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.y; })
      .attr('r', function (d) { return d.r; })
      .style('fill', function(d) { return colorMap[d.data.id]});

  vSlices.append('text')
      .attr('x', function(d,i) {return d.x+(j*300)})
      .attr('y', function(d) {return d.y})
      .attr('text-anchor','middle')
      .text(function(d) {return d.data.children.data.size});

}

//})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Console log shows me that the object property I'm trying to access doesn't exist, but ironically it was the console's mapping of the data structure that lead me to choose `d.data.children.data.size` in the first place.

I'm assuming there is some user error on my end, but I really haven't had success trouble shooting. I've experimented with `d.data.children[0].data.size` and other similar variations, but the error persists.

### Question

Is there an easier fool-proof (arash-proof) way to access the `size` property that seems to be buried deep in `vNodes`? The best I could think of was make a standalone object that might work like: `sizeMap[d.data.id]`, but that would entail so much work, and defeat the purpose of using d3, I feel like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all nodes contain a `size` property in the `data` object. Therefore, you can do something like:

```
return d.data.data.size ? d.data.data.size : null
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 20,
  bottom: 300,
  left: 30,
  right: 100
};

var height = 600;
var width = 1080;

var totalWidth = width + margins.left + margins.right;
var totalHeight = height + margins.top + margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', totalWidth)
  .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

//var tsvData = d3.tsv('circle-pack-data.tsv');

//tsvData.then(function(rawData) {

/*
  var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
    return {id:d.id, parentId:d.parentId, size:+d.size}
  });
*/


var data = [
  [{
      'id': '1Q19'
    },
    {
      'id': 'pooled',
      'parentId': '1Q19',
      'size': 29.5
    },
    {
      'id': 'spv',
      'parentId': '1Q19',
      'size': 11
    },
    {
      'id': 'single',
      'parentId': '1Q19',
      'size': 200
    }
  ],

  [{
      'id': '2Q19'
    },
    {
      'id': 'pooled',
      'parentId': '2Q19',
      'size': 31
    },
    {
      'id': 'spv',
      'parentId': '2Q19',
      'size': 15
    },
    {
      'id': 'single',
      'parentId': '2Q19',
      'size': 171
    }
  ],

  [{
      'id': '3Q19'
    },
    {
      'id': 'pooled',
      'parentId': '3Q19',
      'size': 28
    },
    {
      'id': 'spv',
      'parentId': '3Q19',
      'size': 12
    },
    {
      'id': 'single',
      'parentId': '3Q19',
      'size': 152
    }
  ],

  [{
      'id': '4Q19'
    },
    {
      'id': 'pooled',
      'parentId': '4Q19',
      'size': 25
    },
    {
      'id': 'spv',
      'parentId': '4Q19',
      'size': 214
    },
    {
      'id': 'single',
      'parentId': '4Q19',
      'size': 101
    }
  ],
];

var colorMap = {
  '1Q19': "#e7eef8",
  '2Q19': "#e7eef8",
  '3Q19': "#e7eef8",
  '4Q19': "#e7eef8",
  'pooled': "#f6d18b",
  'spv': "#366092",
  'single': "#95b3d7"
};

for (var j = 0; j < (data.length); j++) {

  var vData = d3.stratify()(data[j]);

  var vLayout = d3.pack().size([250, 250]);

  var vRoot = d3.hierarchy(vData).sum(function(d) {
    return d.data.size;
  });
  var vNodes = vRoot.descendants();
  vLayout(vRoot);

  var thisClass = "circ" + String(j);

  var vSlices = graphGroup.selectAll('.' + thisClass).data(vNodes).attr('class', thisClass).enter().append('g');

  //console.log(vNodes)

  vSlices.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
      return d.x + (j * 300)
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr('r', function(d) {
      return d.r;
    })
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return colorMap[d.data.id]
    });

  vSlices.append('text')
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
      return d.x + (j * 300)
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.y
    })
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.data.size ? d.data.data.size : null
    });

}

//})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```